# Homomorphism between 2 abelian groups sending one given element to another given element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $G'$ be arbitrary abelian groups. Fix a $g \in G$ and $h \in G'$. Then does there exist a homomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi(g) = h$?

Comment: Not necessarily. The only homomorphism from $\mathbb Z / (n)$ to $\mathbb Z$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: Not if $g$ is the identity and $h$ isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n$ and $\phi(e)=e$, it follows that the order of $\phi(g)$ must divide the order of $g$.  This is certainly a restriction on possible values for $\phi(g)$.